# Can you help me make my code a little simpler and shorter please? thanks

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 2000;
var b = 75;
var c = 840;
var d = 28500;
var e = 2000000;
var f = 7.50;
console.log(5 / 100.0 * a);
console.log(5 / 100.0 * b);
console.log(5 / 100.0 * c);
console.log(5 / 100.0 * d);
console.log(5 / 100.0 * e);
console.log(5 / 100.0 * f);
```

It all comes out correctly but how could get the same result with less code?

Comment: Put the vars in an array and loop through it.

Comment: Should be posted on Code Review, not here.

Comment: oh wow, when I posted my answer and the page refreshed...instantly many other answers all relatively the same. @.@

Comment: Young me is dumb, and forever grateful.

Answer (score 4):

Use arrays.

```
var data = [2000, 75, 840, 28500, 2000000, 7.50];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    console.log(5 / 100.0 * data[i]);
```

If you don't want values to be index based you can use objects as well.

```
var data = {
    a: 2000,
    b: 75,
    c: 840,
    d: 28500,
    e: 2000000,
    f: 7.50,
};

for(var key in data)
    console.log(5 / 100.0 * data[key]);
```

Comment: You could put 5/100.0 in a variable and use it in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should try combining the values into an array. Then you can iterate through the array:

```
var values = [2000, 75, 840, 28500, 2000000, 7.50];

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    console.log(5 / 100.0 * values[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var calculate = function(value){ return (5 / 100.0 * value); };
var values = [a,b,c,d,e,f];
for (pos in values ){ console.log(  calculate(values[pos] )); };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [2000,75,840,28500,200000,7.5]
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    console.log(5 / 100.0 * a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, it will looks like this:

```
var arr = [2000, 75, 840, 28500, 2000000, 7.50];

jQuery.each(arr, function() {
  console.log(5 / 100.0 * this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you could stick the values in to an array and loop them:

```
var someNumbers = new Array(2000, 75, 840, 28500, 2000000, 7.50);
for(var number in someNumbers){
    console.log(0.05 * someNumbers[number]);
}
```